# Django2.0 urls.py conversion from url() to path()

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to convert the URL below to a path format I couldn't find a proper way can you help me?

```
url(r'^profile/(?p<pk>\d+)/$', views.profile, name='profile_with_pk'),
```

I am currently using Django 2.0 and want to convert into path format

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit confused. That example is not in either URL or path format, but a mixture of both.

I'm not sure what you actually want to achieve here. The correct old style format would be:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ...
```

and the new style one would be:

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', ...
```